# Wildcard-subdomain with Wordpress Multisite as Subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, wildcard-subdomain, multisite

I have a Wordpress multisite project and the multisite network is configured as subdirectory.
 
Let's say - **domain.com/site1**, **domain.com/site2** (which are working properly).

The server is also configured for wildcard-subdomain.

Now, if I try with **req.domain.com** or **req1.domain.com/site1** or **req2.domain.com/site2** then it always redirect to **domain.com**.

I checked the requested domain name (say for- **req.domain.com**) by print from *<root dir>/index.php*, and up to this */index.php* the domain name (**req.domain.com**) is OK; but it redirected (to **domain.com**) before theme files start to execute.

Is there any way to use both wildcard-subdomain and multisite (subdirectory) simultaneously?